# C/C++: Proper places to use extern for my library?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker, extern

I am making a shared library and its functions remained undefined during linking when built (and linking with a test program), and now I have learned name mangling and why it would cause something like this.

I assume in the libfoo.h header I would put:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
#endif
int foobar();
#ifdef __cplusplus
  }
#endif
```

And would the externs for the prototypes be all I need to apply them to, or would I need to wrap them around the function declarations in libfoo.c as well so my C++ program can read them?

**Update for comment below:**

The linking error is this:

```
g++ prototypes.cxx -L/usr/lib/  -lfoo
/tmp/ccKQmen4.o: In function `main':
prototypes.cxx:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `foobar()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: That look right.. perhaps best if you give us the linking error - perhaps it is a simple as not having linked in the lib properly ?

Comment: I have updated the question with that, although it looks run of the mill linker error.

Comment: do you include libfoo.h in libfoo.cpp? If you do an `nm` on the libfoo.a do you have the c++ name for the foobar() function?

Comment: @PAntione: I do, and this is strange, libfoo.a is 8 bytes (contents `!<arch>`) and nothing else is inside it, even though the .o .lai and .la are relatively good sizes. Maybe I will try the process from scratch.. not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything with the source, as long as you compile it with a C compiler.

That's what you tell the C++ compiler in the header - use C calling and nameing conventions.

Comment: When I create a shared library with the code (.so) and link to it (-lfoo) and create a test program (C++) to use it, when using foobar() it will come up with a linker error of undefined reference (I include the .h with the prototypes), I assumed there is a visibility problem or name mangling..

Comment: On Linux, naming the file libFoo might not be a good idea, as lib* usually means files created by a library tool.

Comment: I am actually using libtool in a makefile and installing the simple library, that is why I am so confused linking to that newly built library does not work!

Answer (score 0):

The C++ FAQ has a whole section devoted to mixing C and C++ http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.4

Basically the only place to put `extern "C"` is in those header files included from C and C++. If you don't have control over those, follow the previous answer (32.3).

Comment: Nope, seems to unfortunately still not be defined when I use the function in my C++ program.. I guess something is wrong with my shared object, I am not sure.